# CORS error reading a file from GCP bucket

Tags: express, google-cloud-platform, cors, swagger-ui

I am trying to show a swagger json file on swagger UI. The file is in a GCP bucket. I am getting following CORS error when I tried to access the file from expressJS.

```
Fetch error
Failed to fetch https://storage.cloud.google.com/openapi.json
Fetch error
Possible cross-origin (CORS) issue? The URL origin (https://storage.cloud.google.com) does not match the page (http://localhost:3001). Check the server returns the correct 'Access-Control-Allow-*' headers.
```

Here is snippet of my code

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require("fs");
var cors = require('cors')
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');

const app = express();
app.use(cors({
  origin: '*'
}));

  var options = {
    swaggerOptions: {
      url: 'https://storage.cloud.google.com/openapi.json'
    }
  }
 
app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(null, options));

app.listen(3001,()=>{
    console.log("server started");
})
```

Comment: Did you set up CORS for your GCP bucket? https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-cors

Comment: @user2570135, did the previous comment address your concern?

Comment: Thanks but It did not work..
[
    {
      "origin": ["http://localhost:3001"],
      "method": ["GET"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "access-control-allow-origin"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]

Comment: -- and --


[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600,
    "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "access-control-allow-origin", "access-control-allow-header"]
  }
]